# Long labels appear to be hidden with "..." - MS Chart Pie Graph control

Tags: c#, asp.net, label, mschart

I would like the labels to be completely visible, and if necessary, just spin the pie chart so that the text will fit without being hidden with "...".

Here is an example

[image: Pie graph with "Received" item that has hidden text]

Anyone know how to fix this so it is not shortened?

This is the control on my asp page.

```
<asp:CHART ID="Chart1" runat="server" 
    BorderColor="181, 64, 1" BorderDashStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2" Height="371px" 
    ImageLocation="~/TempImages/ChartPic_#SEQ(300,3)" ImageType="Png" 
    Palette="None" Width="693px" 
    BorderlineColor="">
        <legends>
            <asp:Legend BackColor="Transparent" Enabled="False" 
                                    Font="Trebuchet MS, 8.25pt, style=Bold" IsTextAutoFit="True" Name="Default">
            </asp:Legend>
        </legends>
        <series>
            <asp:Series ChartArea="ChartArea1" ChartType="Pie" Legend="Default" 
                Name="Series1" 
                CustomProperties="PieLabelStyle=Outside, PieDrawingStyle=Concave"  
                YValuesPerPoint="6" Font="Trebuchet MS, 8.25pt, style=Bold">
                <SmartLabelStyle AllowOutsidePlotArea="No" MaxMovingDistance="100" />
            </asp:Series>
        </series>
        <chartareas>
                        <asp:ChartArea BackColor="#DEEDF7" BackGradientStyle="TopBottom" 
                                    BackSecondaryColor="White" BorderColor="64, 64, 64, 64" BorderDashStyle="Solid" 
                                    Name="ChartArea1" ShadowColor="Transparent">
                            <Area3DStyle Enable3D="True" IsRightAngleAxes="False" />
            </asp:ChartArea>
        </chartareas>
    </asp:CHART>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This time around I think you should have a higher Width value for the Chart.

This link may be of some help:

[How to: Display Data Point Labels Outside a Pie Chart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627437.aspx)

Comment: Hey Leniel :P, I've given it a higher width value, and yes, that works... But I only have 700px to work with. Is there any other way?

Comment: @Mike: You can shorten your labels. That's the only way I can think of.

Comment: Setting a new rotation number on the 3d properties spins the graph around and repositions the text. If I could find a way to check if the label will be shortened, I could change the rotation number until it the label isn't shortened